# Workaround for mouseover in nested ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, mouseover

I’ve been searching for some time and read about ng-repeat creating it’s own scope, but still did not find a solution.

I would like to have a mouseover event fired on each `.event-window element`. Using `ng-mouseover="hoverIn()"` doesn’t work. I expect because of trying to call a function that is not part of the scope, but only part of the parent (parent’s) scope, since the call works fine in elements that are not created with ng-repeat.

```
<div class="day-window" ng-repeat="day in weekObject['days']">
<div ng-repeat="event in day.events track by $index">
    <div class="event-window" ng-style="{'height': (event.length)+'px',
                                         'position': 'absolute',
                                         'top':(1565/24)*(event.offsetTop-1) +'px',
                                         'left': getLeftCoords(event.colliding)+'%',
                                         'width': 100/event.colliding+'%',
                                         'background': event.color,
                                         'opacity': 0.8}" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()">
        <p>{{event.title}}</p>
        <p>[{{event.startTime |date:'H:mm'}} - {{event.endTime |date:'H:mm'}}]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.hoverIn = function() {
    alert('hoverIn');
}
```

The hover in my css doesn’t work as well. Is it overridden by ng-style?

```
.event-window:hover {
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

You can find a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19168/), but I'm not able to replicate the problem. There must be some error in my code.

Comment: seem to have some curly quotes in your code... make sure it is rendering properly in the dom. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Just an FYI, if you're trying to call "hoverIn()" which is in the parent scope, it should still work. ng-repeat does create an isolated scope, but it should inherit from the parent scope.

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks for pointing that out, I did some text formatting in an editor that created curly quotes before posting this question. I will try to make a demo.

Comment: @jValdron: Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: It works in your demo..so whats the problem?

Comment: The code in my question doesn't work

Comment: I let someone else watch my screen, and it turned out I overlooked a z-index in one of the parent classes....